# Stairs pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This function in Javascript doesn't works as desired. But when written in C, it works as desired.

```
 var patt_2 = function()
     {
       for(i=5;i>=1;i--)
       {
          for(j=1;j<i;j++)
          {
            $("#panel8").append(" ");
          }
          for(k=5;k>=i;k--)
          {
            $("#panel8").append("*");
          }
          $("#panel8").append("<br/>");
       }
    };
```

#### Undesired output

[image: Undesired output]

#### Desired Output

[image: Desired output]

Comment: Try with `$("#panel8").append("&nbsp;&nbsp;");` instead of `$("#panel8").append(" ");`

Comment: ay thanks! it worked. :)

Comment: You can also use a `<pre>` tag to avoid "losing" blank spaces in html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could give your `#panel8` element the following to allow for non `&nbsp;` characters to also allow multiple whitespace:

```
#panel8 {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

You can [read here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-prop) what this does, quote:

> This value prevents user agents from collapsing sequences of white space. Lines are only broken at preserved newline characters.

Basically HTML collapses whitespace characters (`" "`) to create one space, if you use `&nbsp;` you overcome this issue but creates uglier code in general (since you'll have to append `"&nbsp;"` to your string all the time).

If your element can have `white-space: pre;` then this is a clean and easy solution which doesn't require you to edit your script!

P.S. It's not JS in which it's not working but rather HTML or the HTML parser that collapses the whitespace.

Comment: Also OP would probably need to set a monospace font.